# How can I align an object in CSS next to my page navigation

Tags: html, css

I can't get the object (select form linked to page as an object) to center right with the navigation buttons.

I tried making columns for it, making it have its own class and using padding, the display inline/inline-block

```js
var urlMenu = document.getElementById('chapterMenu');
urlMenu.onchange = function() {
  var userOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (userOption.value != "blank") {
    window.open("webpage" + userOption.value + ".html", "_parent");
  }
}
```

```css
.chapterselect {
  display: inline-block;
}

.chapterselect a {
  padding: 1000px;
}

/*for the next previous buttons*/
.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/*end of next previous buttons*/
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="webpage 1.html">❮❮</a>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="webpage 1.html">❮</a>
</div>
<div class="chapterselect">
  <object data="chapterSelectform.html"></object>
</div>
<div class="pagination disabled">
  <a>❯</a>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="webpage 2.html">❯❯</a>
</div>

<form name="chapterSelect">
  <select name="chapterMenu" id="chapterMenu">
    <option value="blank" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value=" 1">1</option>
    <option value=" 2">2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

When I import it as an object it looks like this [drop down box imported](https://oi217.photobucket.com/albums/cc317/superdbgtfan/drop%20down%20box%20progress%202%20croped.jpg?t=1562724548).
If I don't import it as an object it looks like this [drop down box in page](https://oi217.photobucket.com/albums/cc317/superdbgtfan/drop%20down%20box%20progress%20cropped.jpg?t=1562724686). I want it to line up with the navigation buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the navigation HTML inside a parent container to separate form and navigation elements. Wrap both inside another container. Give them a flexbox layout. You can align them easily using Flexbox properties like `justify-content` and `align-self`.

```js
var urlMenu = document.getElementById('chapterMenu');
urlMenu.onchange = function() {
  var userOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (userOption.value != "blank") {
    window.open("webpage" + userOption.value + ".html", "_parent");
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.form-container {
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/*for the next previous buttons*/

.chapterselect {
  display: inline-block;
}

.chapterselect a {
  padding: 1000px;
}

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/*end of next previous buttons*/

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pagination-container">
    <div class="pagination">
      <a href="webpage 1.html">❮❮</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
      <a href="webpage 1.html">❮</a>
    </div>
    <div class="chapterselect">
      <object data="chapterSelectform.html"></object>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination disabled">
      <a>❯</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
      <a href="webpage 2.html">❯❯</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form name="chapterSelect" class="form-container">
    <select name="chapterMenu" id="chapterMenu">
      <option value="blank" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value=" 1">1</option>
      <option value=" 2">2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work but I think something else is going on since even if I change the background to red in the style sheet for it it won't show up.

Comment: But it works in the snippet right? You should be producing a full demo then :)

Comment: A problem I was having was I needed a style set in the file I was importing for it to read it at all, still have a problem but its a different problem which is probably about as close as I seem to get it to right.

Comment: You might want to open a new question for that if it is not related to this.